# Visual Studio Code files.autoSave onFocusChange not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup my visual studio code editor to auto save files on focus change.

Reading the setting documentation, I've set up my setting.json file for the project like this:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
        "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"
    }
}
```

But when I make changes to a file, then switch to a different file nothing happens (I still have to save the file manually).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where can I find this options?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The option "files.autoSave" should be out of the "files.exclude" section.

```
   "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
    },
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"
```

Answer (score 12):

In VS Code, Enable the function using File > Auto Save